# How to use monte carlo method to simulate two dices

Tags: python-3.x, function, iterable

I'm trying to simulate the distribution of adding two dice using the monte carlo method.

however, an error is showing up and i'm not sure why.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random
from statistics import mean, stdev

die_one = random.randint(1,6)

die_two = random.randint(1,6)

def test():

    dice_added = [die_one + die_two for _ in range(1000)]

    return dice_added

tests = [test()]

plt.hist(mean(tests))
```

it always shows a "can't convert type 'list' to numerator/denominator" error message

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems:

1. The following line nests the return value (which is already a list) inside another list:

   ```
   tests = [test()]
   ```

   change it to

   ```
   tests = test()
   ```
2. You initialise `dice_one` and `dice_two` outside the function and use the same values 1000 times. Try this instead:

   ```
   dice_added = [random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(1000)]
   ```